# CRON не отправляет email. Почему?

Tags: php, cron

CRON не отправляет письма по завершению выполнения задачи, но отправляет, если в скрипте была какая-то ошибка.

Как сделать, чтобы крон при любом исходе присылал отчет, независимо есть ли ошибка ?

Comment: самому вызвать ошибку?)

Comment: слишком просто )

Comment: ну...вы покажите хоть чуть-чуть, что там у вас в скрипте? =)

Comment: Так дело не в скрипте, а в кроне. Я элементарно пустой файл создаю и добавляют в крон на выполнение. После выполнения не приходит ответа на почту, но если добавляю в скрипт какую-нибудь ошибку, то тогда приходит

Comment: в cron что написано?

Comment: `MAILTO="test@inbox.ru"
PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin"

5 0,12 * * * php /var/www/www-root/data/www/test/index.php`

Comment: все стало понятно. Почему-то mail.ru блолирует письма от крона

Comment: Хм...Никогда не сталкивался....  У меня письма отправляются PHPMailer` ом по SMTP, скрипт которого, я запускаю cron`ом.